# Can I have my Mac automatically connect to a network store on login?

Tags: network, storage, automation

I would like my MacBook Pro to automatically connect to a particular network volume whenever possible.

Are there ways to automate this?

Answer (score 1):

First, connect your network volume through finder (cmd+K).

Then, in system preferences go to "Users & Groups" and click on the tab "**Login Items**". Here you can add volumes that will be mounted automatically after login. Just click the add button, navigate to the network volume and click add.